# Xampp Apache server not responding to request

Tags: windows-8, xampp, apache2.4

I have installed Xampp server (xampp-win32-5.6.8-0-VC11-installer) on Windows 8 64 bit os. I have deployed the `HelloWorld` application folder in `htdocs` directory and added a virtual host in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file like below

```
 <VirtualHost localhost:80>
  DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/
  RewriteEngine On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName localhost
  <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/Aasifeweb/app/>
   Require all granted
   Allow from all
</Directory>
  <Location />
  ProxyPass   http://localhost/Aasifeweb/app/#/home
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost/Aasifeweb/app/#/home
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  / http://localhost/Aasifeweb/app/#/home
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache error Log file

```
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.149126 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2684:tid 448] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.200160 2015] [core:warn] [pid 2684:tid 448] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.268206 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2684:tid 448] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.298225 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2684:tid 448] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.298225 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2684:tid 448] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.298225 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2684:tid 448] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.301227 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2684:tid 448] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3576
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:20
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.763535 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3576:tid 448] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.885617 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3576:tid 448] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:26.918638 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3576:tid 448] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri Aug 07 19:23:29.637450 2015] [mpm_winnt:error] [pid 3576:tid 4852] AH00326: Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting
```

This problem occurs when i add virtual host configuration to the httpd-vhosts.conf file. When i remove the virtual host, the server seems to respond. The deployed application is written in angular-js framework

**Important**: The request seems to be appending the resource path again and again. But, I'm not sure why this happens?

```
GET /Aasifeweb/app/%23/homeAasifeweb/app/%23/homeAasifeweb/app/%23/homeAasifeweb/app/%23
```

When I hit `http://localhost` in browser, it keeps loading. There are lot of solutions in the internet, but nothing works for me.

*Things I have tried to solve the problem*

- I have done `netsh winsock reset`
- I have changed the port of the
  apache server
- I have disabled skype and antivirus

Please let me know your views

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `ProxyPass   http://localhost/Aasifeweb/app/#/home` directive of `localhost:80`? Right now this reads like an endless loop: "please pass any request XYZ for me (that is, for `http://localhost:80/XYZ`) to `http://localhost:80/Aasifeweb/app/#/homeXZY`". Because this request is for localhost:80 the rule is applied again, leading to an ever-growing trail of `/Aasifeweb/app/%23/homeAasifeweb/app/%23/homeAasifeweb/app/%23/homeAasifeweb/app/%23` and the exhaustion of all threads on your server (`AH00326: Server ran out of threads to serve requests`)

Comment: Thank you, Christoph. I was able to resolve this issue. There is no need for proxy pass at all. I just added the app folder to the document root directive. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have to use `ProxyPass` at all. I just had to point the directory and Angularjs - `ng-route` takes care of page routing.

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
  DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/Aasifeweb/app
</VirtualHost>
```